# No speedup using asyncio for uploading a list of files using resumable upload links

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-asyncio

I have a list of file paths and their resumable upload links for uploading to GCS buckets. I implemented this normally and then using asyncio, and find no improvements in the speed of execution. Would appreciate any inputs, thanks.

```
from asyncio import run, gather
import requests 

async def uploadFile(UPLOAD_URL, LOCAL_PATH):
    with open(LOCAL_PATH, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read()
    requests.put(UPLOAD_URL, data=data)

async def uploadFiles(path_and_url):
    uploads = [uploadFile(dic['upload_url'], dic['local_path']) for dic in path_and_url]
    await gather(*uploads)

run(uploadFiles(path_and_url))
```

Using async functions in the `uploadFile` option speeds up my code by about 15%, anything further I can do? Thanks!

```
import aiohttp, aiofiles

async def uploadFile(UPLOAD_URL, LOCAL_PATH):
    async with aiofiles.open(LOCAL_PATH, 'rb') as f:
        data = await f.read()
    # httpx.put(UPLOAD_URL, data=data)
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.put(UPLOAD_URL, data=data) as resp:
                print(f"{LOCAL_PATH} -> {resp}")

async def uploadFiles(path_and_url):
    uploads = [uploadFile(dic['upload_url'], dic['local_path']) for dic in path_and_url]
    await gather(*uploads)
```

Comment: "uploadFile" only uses synchronous functions (no "await") therefore only one of these invocations runs at once.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelButscher, I understand it now. Quick search and I can see libraries like aiofiles, aiohttp and httpx. I'll try using them

Comment: @SurajSubramanian use `aiohttp` instead of  `requests`

Comment: That makes asynchronous requests without blocking I/O

Comment: @ArtyomVancyan Yes mate, that's what I did and it speeded up by about 15-20% (based on my testing with a small folder tho). I've updated my question with the new code, looking for further improvements :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you did is not wrong there are some optimizations I have made it can speed up your code as well. You were creating a new session on every file upload which is not optimal and could spend more time and resources than creating it once and using it for all requests.

```
import asyncio

import aiofiles
import aiohttp


async def upload_file(session, upload_url, local_path):
    async with aiofiles.open(local_path, 'rb') as fp:
        file_content = await fp.read()
        response = session.put(upload_url, data=file_content)


async def upload_files(paths):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        await asyncio.gather(*[upload_file(session, **path) for path in paths])


async def main():
    await upload_files([
        {'upload_url': 'https://.../', 'local_path': '/home/suraj/Downloads/1.png'},
        {'upload_url': 'https://.../', 'local_path': '/home/suraj/Downloads/2.png'},
        {'upload_url': 'https://.../', 'local_path': '/home/suraj/Downloads/3.png'},
        {'upload_url': 'https://.../', 'local_path': '/home/suraj/Downloads/4.png'},
    ])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: That makes sense! I'll give this a shot :)